# Ruby and Rhodes

Tags: ruby, rhodes

We need to develop a cross-platform mobile web app for iOS, Android, Blackberry and Windows7.

It will read users' Geo location and suggest places nearby they might be interested in visiting. The database will be proprietary, not drawing from third parties. Server side changes to filter through to the interface without needing to rebuild the app.

Ruby is the preferred language. I have read some of the threads here on Rhodes. My sense is to go with Ruby and the Rhodes framework, but would like to know if there is a better option I am overlooking?

If we choose Ruby with Rhodes, is it better to use Redis instead of mySQL for the database?

Answer (score 2):

Rhodes is a good framework for building mobile applications, if you want Ruby as language, it is the only choice.

As for the database, I'd go with Redis, it is better supported, it is used by Rhosync, and it performs better than mysql.

You can also consider [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/)

But I'm not sure that it already supports WP7..

Answer (score 0):

Redis is the server-side database used by RhoConnect (formerly RhoSync). There will be work on your part if you really want to modify the RhoConnect source code to interact with mySQL instead of Redis.

Mobile applications built with Rhodes will use either SQLite (iOS, Android, Windows) or hsqldb (BB) on the devices themselves, not Redis or mySQL.